# Weird node.js' require behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been using node.js for about a year, and I always did that kind of stuff. But for some reason (maybe it's related to 0.8.x) now when I do it, it doesn't work anymore.

Here's some code:

Let's say I have `test.js`:

```
var test = {
    datFunction: function(){ return 'oh yeah'; }
}
module.exports = test;
```

and I have `test2.js`:

```
var test = require('./test');

// should output:
// { datFunction: [function] }
console.log(test);

// but outputs:
// {}
```

As I commented up there, it usually log'd the object with everything that was in there, but now it only gives me `{}`.

Any idea why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export `test` in `test.js`

```
module.exports = test;
```

Comment: I forgot it, but it does the same with it. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Make sure it's `module.exports` your edit says `module.export`.

Comment: holy crap. sorry and thanks. sublime text highlights module.export so i thought it was right but both gets highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about node.js but it seems you have a redeclaration of `var test`.

Comment: it doesn't matter with node.js since these are 2 separate files, and one simply require the other and receive the function without the name of it. but thanks for responding anyways :-)